# Run Command directly from Powershell file

Tags: powershell

[image]

I am get above error, when i am trying to run command from .ps1 file.

Please let me know, how to run command directly from powershell prompt,Without double clicking on this file.

Sorry for asking such a simple question.
Regards,
Param

Comment: Is that the full content of the file? Does the file import any modules before running this script? Are you running it on a server / workstation with active directory commandlets in place?

Comment: @Param: if you type in the command    'Import-Module ActiveDirectory' does Powershell load anything? or do you get another error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be missing an `Import-Module` call:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module ActiveDirectory
PS C:\> # Now, New-ADUser should be recognized
```

By default, PowerShell 2.0 will throw an error if you attempt to import a module already loaded in the session, so the "failsafe" version of the above would be:

```
# Unless -ListAvailable is present, Get-Module only returns already-imported modules 
if(-not(Get-Module ActiveDirectory)){
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to add `.\` in front the `.ps1` file.

For example `.\Backup.ps1`